# Create SVG paths around objects headless

Tags: javascript, php, svg

I am using Gimp to create SVG masks around example 10 to 100 objects in a PNG image like this.

1. Click background with select tool. Always xy 1,1
2. Invert selection
3. Convert selection to path
4. Export path to SVG.

the PNG is only 2 or 3 colors. Why it is easy to do in gimp. However I would like to do this headless with image magic or like. Because I need to do this around 100+ Times every week. In the future maybe more.

No. 1 option is if this is possible to do in PHP GD as all images is generated in PHP.

Comment: You may want to investigate an automatic vector tracing tool such as `potrace`.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I've tested Potrace and Autotrace. One of these might be an option.